# How to connect to docker kafka container from Kafkaesque tool?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, bitnami, bitnami-kafka

I am trying to be able to play around with some topics on my local machine.

For this I want to use Kafkaesque https://kafka.esque.at/

My spring boot application has the following configurations:

I found out a docker image that I added in the docker-compose file  from bitnami that looks like this for setting up the environment

```
zookeeper:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.8
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "zookeeper_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.4
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9080:8080"
      - "9081:9081"
      - "9082-9084:9082-9084"
    volumes:
      - "kafka_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=no
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  schema-registry:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/schema-registry:7.3
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKA_BROKERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
```

In my local application properties I set the configuration like this

```
spring.kafka:
  bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  properties:
    schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
  streams:
    cleanup.on-startup: true
```

In kafkaesque (https://kafka.esque.at/) I set  the properties like this

[image]

My case is the one presented in scenario 4 here
https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should look for how to connect to Kafka behind proxy or when in docker container. Most likely the issue is, that IP address assigned to container is something like 10.x.y.z, while you are connecting to 127.0.0.1. This should break Kafka protocol between client (Kafkesque) and server (Kafka). Here is good enough explanation in this [article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/).

As alternative, you may look for how to put kafkaesque into docker container. Which is not trivial, since Desktop GUI applications are not well supported in docker container.

Otherwise, web-based Kafka GUI applications already exist as containers that you can try instead.